# Can we put multiple keys and values at a time in Map using Java

Tags: java, hashmap, guava

Here is what I do. I have a list of objects to be converted to map with key as object id and value as an object. I have thousands of objects in the list and it is causing a performance issue. Is there any simple way to do it without using a loop or use some other dataset?

```
final List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
final Map<Id, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<Id, Object>();

for (final Object object : objects)
{
    objectMap.put(object.getId(), object);
}
```

Comment: No. The loop will always be present in the code in an explicit or implicit form. There is no other way to iterate over a collection.

Comment: checky check out this then https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/

Comment: Have you tried the proposed optimizations?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to optimize the `HashMap` with the right capacity and load factor:

> An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance: initial capacity and load factor. The capacity is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created. The load factor is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.

The best value for capacity is `n / lf` so adding elements will not trigger the rehash where `n` is the max element count and `lf` the load factor. The default load factor is 0.75 but you can set it in the constructor to meet your need.

> The expected number of entries in the map and its load factor should be taken into account when setting its initial capacity, so as to minimize the number of rehash operations. If the initial capacity is greater than the maximum number of entries divided by the load factor, no rehash operations will ever occur.

The default values make your map rehash the elements many times with so many put operations and this impacts the performances

The loop is mandatory, made by you or by the collector.

Comment: @Teg that was an uneducated guess, I admit I should not post things without fact-checking. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to invoke parallel stream on the list:

```
objects.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toMap(object -> object.getId(), object -> object));
```

or else see some more of Java 8 parallel capabilities in the [Parallelism Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html)

Comment: You will get a better performance if you use a concurrent HashMap collector. i.e: toConcurrentMap instead of toMap

Answer (score 1):

The use of java 8's Stream won't spare you the iteration over the list but might be slightly more optimised than repeated puts :

```
final List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
final Map<Id, Object> objectMap = objects.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getId(), e -> e));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using stream to convert List to Map. But anyway internally loop is used.

```
Map<Id, Object> objectMap = objects.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(Object ::getId, Object));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run a jmh benchmark with one million objects to compare what is best.

forloop:  26.191 ± 0.567  ms/op

java8 Parallel:  42.693 ± 1.784  ms/op

Guava.uniqueIndex:  38.097 ± 3.521  ms/op

It seems that the for loop is the fastest!

Here is the benchmark: (MyObject extends Object and has an ID integer field)

```html
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Fork(5)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class ZipIteratorBenchmark {

   static ArrayList<MyObject> objects;

   @Setup(Level.Trial)
   public void setup() {
      objects = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
         objects.add(new MyObject(i));
      }
   }

   @Benchmark
   public static Map<Integer, MyObject> forloop() {
      final Map<Integer, MyObject> objectMap = new HashMap<>();

      for (final MyObject object : objects) {
         objectMap.put(object.getId(), object);
      }
      return objectMap;
   }

   @Benchmark
   public static Map<Integer, MyObject> toMap() {
      return FluentIterable.from(objects).uniqueIndex(MyObject::getId);
   }

   @Benchmark
   public static Map<Integer, MyObject> java8Parallel() {
    return  objects.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(MyObject::getId, object -> object));
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to put the HashMap capacity in the for loop test please?

Comment: When I set the HashMap capacity, I get 24.056 ± 0.973 ms/op

Comment: Less total time but more ms/op?

Comment: Not really, 24.056 ± 0.973 ms/op  means 24.056 ms/op with error of 0.973 ms/op. So setting a capacity for the hashmap improves the performance.

Comment: Thank you, in my test, with capacity = 1.000.000 and load factor = 1 I get 50% less time

Comment: Did you run both scenarios (with and without load factor) on your machine ? 
as it may differ between different machines.

Comment: Yes, without load factor = 1 you must increase the capacity or get rehases and performances are worse